# Tried attaching the particle effect named Fall_Particleeffect_Leaves_01 to a slider script that changes the emission, but I struggle with it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, slider, particles

So the original idea was to attach the particle effect emission to the SeasonIntensitySlider, so that when the slider value is changed, the emission value is changed.

I wasn't able to get that done, so now I tried using the same input that changes the slider value to also change the emission value at the same time - which didn't work either (and was a band-aid fix as well). And I think I still got the wrong code for what I'm trying in the first place.

I attached the code below. Can anyone tell me how I can link them?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SeasonIntensity : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider SeasonIntensitySlider;

    public void Start()
    {
        SeasonIntensitySlider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { ValueChangeCheck(); }); //Adds a listener to the main slider and invokes a method when the value changes.
    }

    public void ValueChangeCheck()
    {
        Debug.Log(SeasonIntensitySlider.value); // Invoked when the value of the slider changes.
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f) //Foward
        {
            SeasonIntensitySlider.value += 0.1f;
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f) //Backwards
        {
            SeasonIntensitySlider.value -= 0.1f;
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f) //Foward
        {
            ParticleSystem ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
            var em = ps.emission;
            em.enabled = true;

            em.rateOverTime += 5f;
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f) //Backwards
        {
            ParticleSystem ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
            var em = ps.emission;
            em.enabled = true;

            em.rateOverTime -= 5f;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, i recommend to you to clean up a little your code. Put the particle system reference on top. Then assign it all from start. You have not to declare so many variables (because it's in update and every frame new unnecessary variable is created. It consumes fps). Then make only 2 if statements instead of 4, you can fit this in only 2 if's.

And for the problem, maybe check if you've assigned the slider variable and i know different method of adding listener. `AddListener(() => ValueChangeCheck());`

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SeasonIntensity : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider SeasonIntensitySlider;
    private var em;

    public void Start()
    {
        SeasonIntensitySlider.onValueChanged.AddListener(() => ValueChangeCheck()); //Adds a listener to the main slider and invokes a method when the value changes.

        em = GetComponnent<ParticleEffect>().emission;
    }

    public void ValueChangeCheck()
    {
         Debug.Log(SeasonIntensitySlider.value); // Invoked when the value of the slider changes.
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f) //Foward
        {
            SeasonIntensitySlider.value += 0.1f;

            em.enabled = true;
            em.rateOverTime += 5;
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f) //Backwards
        {
            SeasonIntensitySlider.value -= 0.1f;

            em.enabled = true;
            em.rateOverTime -= 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been helpful, thanks!

But I get two errors from this code, one being CS0825 "The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code." and CS1593 "Delegate 'UnityAction<float>' does not take 0 arguments".

How can I fix these issues? I just looked them up but it's just so much more confusing now.

Comment: For the var error, try using object or try finding its own syntax reference. Maybe ParticleEffect.Emission or howewer is it called.

Comment: have you tried () => function?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).